# DateTime from CFDirectory not being interpreted correctly by ColdFusion

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We have Coldfusion installed on Windows Server 2003

A dump of CFDirectory on the undelivered mail returns the following:

[image]

But the problem is upon iterating this query, when I dump the date with:

```
#dateFormat(mailStubs.DateLastModified,'dd-mmm-yyyy')#
```

This is what I get:

11-Nov-2026
11-Nov-2027
11-Nov-2028
11-Nov-2029
11-Nov-2029
11-Nov-2029
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930
11-Nov-1930

So doing:

```
datediff("n", mailStubs.DateLastModified, now())
```

now() being 30th Nov 2011 lets say 2:00 PM gives me very weird results

This only happens on Windows server 2003 (Our production server), it worked fine on my local system (XP)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a really old thread, but ... `cfdirectory` returns a *localized* date string (not date object). So you should be using the `LS` (locale sensitive) date functions to parse it. The reason is that the standard CF date functions (`DateFormat`, `ParseDateTime`, ...) **always** use U.S. date conventions. Since the U.S. convention is month first, you will get the wrong results if you pass in a "dd-mm-yyyyy" date string. (At least some of the time.)

```
<cfscript>
   setLocale("en_GB");
   WriteOutput( dateFormat(lsParseDateTime("26/11/11 2:42 PM"), "dd-mmm-yyyy") );
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your modified dates are coming out in a format that dateFormat() doesn't recognise.

Try using a java SimpleDateFormat to convert to a cf "{ts}" date.
You create a SimpleDateFormat + ParsePosition, then in your loop, call the sdf.parse() method and reset the position with pp.setIndex(0)

If you want this to only run on your windows 2003 server, check the server scope `server.os.version`

```
<cfscript>
// init the class with a pattern that matches your wacky date string
// do this before you start looping
var sdf = createObject('java','java.text.SimpleDateFormat').init('dd/MM/yy HH:mm a');

// init a parse position, so the above class knows it's position during parsing
var pp = createObject('java','java.text.ParsePosition').init(0);

// run your loop
for ( var i = 1; i lte query.recordCount; i++ ) {

    // convert the string date into a cf {ts} date.
    cfdate = sdf.parse( query.myColumn[i], pp );

    // reset the position for the next .parse() call
    pp.setIndex(0);

    // now you can use dateDiff() with your cfdate
    // if the parse fails, cfdate will be undefined, so check with an isNull()
}
</cfscript>
```

Simple demonstration of it working:

```
<cfscript>
var dirty = [
    '26/11/11 2:42 PM',
    '27/11/11 10:53 PM',
    '29/11/11 12:08 AM'
];

var sdf = createObject('java','java.text.SimpleDateFormat').init('dd/MM/yy HH:mm a');
var pp = createObject('java','java.text.ParsePosition').init(0);

var clean = [];
for ( var i = 1; i lte arrayLen( dirty ); i++ ) {
    clean[i] = sdf.parse( dirty[i], pp );
    pp.setIndex(0);
}
writeDump( var: dirty );
writeDump( var: clean );
</cfscript>
```

SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

ParsePosition is a simple class used by Format and its subclasses to keep track of the current position during parsing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html